# How to add lab process step that starts a RDP session?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build-process, coded-ui-tests

Im working with VS2010 and TFS and the Coded UI tests (CUIT).

I created some CUIT and added them to several Test Cases in Microsoft Test Manager 2010.
These tests are executed in our build-deploy-test steps.

This looks as follows (simplified):

1. Build application
2. Deploy
   2a. Set snapshot of the Virtual Machine to which the application will be deployed to the snapshot in which the application is not installed
   2b. Install application
3. Run tests

Step 3 contains Coded UI tests, but they cannot be executed (will fail), since there is no active remote desktop connection, which they need to be executed.

Now I would like to add a build step 2c. That automatically connects to the Remote Desktop so that the Coded UI Tests kan be executed.

How should I create this step in the Process Template?

Answer (score 0):

I attempted this myself by running a PowerShell script to connect to a machine via Remote Desktop (see [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-XM/windows-vista/Use-command-line-parameters-with-Remote-Desktop-Connection) to see how to use the Remote Desktop command-line utility).

This didn't really work for me personally because I was running this script from the build machine - which I could only connect to via Remote Desktop - and so when I close Remote Desktop it would close the session on the build machine and thus I would not be able to obtain a remote desktop connection with my test environment (plus it wasn't ideal to have to launch Remote Desktop from the build machine).

Therefore, the solution I went with instead was to enable auto-logon on the test environment (there are various ways to do this, I can't remember how I did it, but it's easily Googled).

So in my PowerShell script, which launched from our build machine, I used a command to remotely restart the test environment. With auto-logon enabled, the test environment would start back up with an active session, then I could carry on with Visual Studio Coded UI testing. This worked for me without any issues.

The command I used was something like this:

> Shutdown.exe /r \\mytestenvironment

[Here is some documentation for it.](http://www.computerhope.com/shutdown.htm). If you intend on using this command to remotely restart a computer, don't forget to give your machine permissions on the test environment, otherwise this command won't work.

I then launched a command to sleep for a few minutes, to give time for the remote test environment to start back up again (with an active session), then I launched the tests.

Personally, I used a PowerShell script but you could also use a DOS/Batch script if you are more familiar with that.

Also, are you trying to run the automated tests as part of a build process template?

Let me know if you need any further help.

Comment: @ Ciaran Have you tried this with VSTS new task build definitions.  I have set up set up a task build definition and have followed the instruction to enabled autologon. 

 My task build on VSTS build definition still blows up unless i have an RDP session session open.  For the command script that you were talking about how is that set up.  I"m new to setting up powershell script.  I'm trying to set up a build definition as a scheduled build so the process can be automated.  Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: I haven't been using VSTS at all. It doesn't have to be a PowerShell script, it could just be a simply .BAT file which contains the commands. I used the Windows Task scheduler to automate the execution of the scripts at the time I needed it to happen.